# How to save custom fields in different forms to a single table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, custom-controls

I am having an *admin form* to add custom fields to any forms.

l had completed the rendering of those custom fields within that forms with help of Editor template.

My table structure is giving below of table

```
[CustomFieldSelectedValueID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[KeyID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Type] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
[CustomFieldSelectedValue] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
```

**The problem** is i need to save custom fields across many forms that is already defined within the admin side.

I can achieve with the entity *Association Technique*,but it need rebuild of the class file can i achieve this functionality without rebuild and reupload.